# Salvar logs do CloudWatch no meu Bucket Pessoal - AWS

Tags: amazon-aws

Fala galera,

Gostaria de salvar os logs do meu CloudWatch dentro do meu bucket pessoal e não no bucket padrão da amazon para que eu possa baixar esses logs com mais facilidade.

Alguém já fez isso ou sabe se é possível?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você pode fazer um script que roda na sua instância e que faz o upload dos logs para um bucket pessoal seu. Usando o AWS CLI é bem simples fazer isso (`aws s3 cp ...`, ou `aws s3 sync ...`). É simples também configurar um cron job para rodar seu script.

Comment: Isso geraria um custo de transferência excessivo.

Comment: A que custo de transferência você se refere exatamente? Custo de "Data Transfer IN" do S3 é 0. Custo de transferência de saída do EC2 para o S3 na mesma região também é 0. Assim, não há custo de transferência com a estratégia que comentei acima, desde que seu bucket esteja na mesma região que a sua instância. Por outro lado, se vc estiver falando de servidor fora do EC2, vc teria o custo do tráfego de saída do seu DC, que seria o mesmo que vc mandar os logs pro CloudWatch -- novamente, não há custo adicional. Referencias: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ e http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrei em contato com a Amazon e eles confirmaram que, infelizmente, ainda não é possível salvar os logs do CloudWatch em um Bucket específico. Qualquer nova informação eu aviso aqui.